# Live text search jquery, wrong selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, search, text, live

So i'm pretty new to this, please bear with me :)

And it's kinda working for me, this is what I have:

HTML:

```
<form id="live-search" action="" class="styled" method="post">
<fieldset>
    <input type="text" class="text-input" id="filter" value="" placeholder="Søg efter skole..." />
    <span id="filter-count"></span>
</fieldset>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#filter").keyup(function(){

    // Retrieve the input field text and reset the count to zero
    var filter = $(this).val(), count = 0;

    // Loop through the comment list
    $(".ss_voting_manual .ss_voting_entry_list").find("li").each(function(){

        // If the list item does not contain the text phrase fade it out
        if ($(this).text().search(new RegExp(filter, "i")) < 0) {
            $(this).fadeOut();

        // Show the list item if the phrase matches and increase the count by 1
        } else {
            $(this).show();
            count++;
        }
    });

    // Update the count
    var numberItems = count;
    $("#filter-count").text("Klasser fundet = "+count);
});
});
```

But when I make a search it do find the `li`, but it lose most of the style, if you see the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tp9RM.jpg) it will make better sense then I can do in writing.

```
 <div id="manual_voting" class="ss_voting_manual">
<ul class="ss_voting_entry_list">
  <li class="my_db_entry item_handle_22924874" id="my_db_entry_22924874" style="">
    <div class="entry_title entry_details">
      <h4>Koge Handelsskole - 3C</h4>
    </div>

    <div class="entry_photo">
      <ol>
        <li style="display: list-item;"><img alt="" src=
        "https://d2ndy3xguswqvu.cloudfront.net/images/220405/22924874/original_89bf1593506cabda8ec9fd63ac6e35d0.png"></li>
      </ol>
    </div>

    <div class="entry_votes entry_details">
      <span class="votes">65</span> Stemmer
    </div>

    <div class="entry_description entry_details ss_preserve_ws"></div>

    <div class="itemActions entry_actions">
      <ul>
        <li class="item_vote" style="display: inline;"><a class="vote_link vote"
        href="#" onclick=
        "SST.vote_for(widget_14972805, 22924874, this); return false;">Stem</a></li>

        <li class="item_share" style="display: inline;"><a class="share_link" href=
        "#" onclick="ss_share(widget_14972805, 22924874); return false;">Del med dine
        venner</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="clear"></div>
  </li>

  <li class="my_db_entry item_handle_22924821" id="my_db_entry_22924821" style=
  "display: list-item;">
    <div class="entry_title entry_details">
    </div>

    <div class="clear"></div>
  </li>
</ul>

<div class="clear"></div>

<div class="ss_voting_paging" id="paging_voting"></div>
```

Comment: The link to the Live text search function is pointing to your screenshot link.

Comment: Do you have a link to the HTML?

Comment: @hitautodestruct oh yeah, sorry about that, well it's almost the same as the html and jq i posted here.

Comment: @maschm It's difficult to understand what's going wrong with your script as the image you posted only shows the bug you're getting but not the wanted result. Can you post a before and after? Or use jsbin.com or jsfiddle.net for a live code example?
FYI you can edit your question http://stackoverflow.com/posts/16333217/edit.

Comment: @maschm Without any extra information anyone reading this question will not be able to help you. Can you at least show the html part your are trying to acces with `.ss_voting_manual .ss_voting_entry_list`?
This may help figure out your issue.

Comment: @hitautodestruct i see you point. sorry for the lack of information. The screenshot from my post is the before, here I made no search so it looks as it should with the title, img, vote "stem", share "Del med dine venner" all as it should be. 

Here you can see what happens when i do a search [After](http://imgur.com/KBuHNhv) an on an other search [After continue] (http://imgur.com/Zo1FISL) the img, disappears each time and the buttons do on the last screenshot.

Comment: @maschm Your issue could be stemming from the fact that your code is hiding the `li`'s holding your images instead of the comment li's. Unfortunately, without the html it's hard to tell...

Comment: @hitautodestruct thanks for taking your time helping, i have just posted some of the HTML, hope i got it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Wrong Selector

In your target code you are searching for all the `li`'s under `.ss_voting_manual .ss_voting_entry_list` including grand children.

```
$(".ss_voting_manual .ss_voting_entry_list").find("li")
```

This is causing your grandchildren `li`'s, the one's that are wrapping the `img` tags, to be hidden.

### Solution

Change your selector to fetch only direct descendant `li`'s:

```
$(".ss_voting_manual .ss_voting_entry_list").children("li")
```

or

```
 $(".ss_voting_manual .ss_voting_entry_list > li")
```

This will only fetch the first direct set of `li`'s after the `ul`.

Comment: Thank you sooo much! using .children instead of .find did it.
Again thank you, much appreciate.